# Why is ruleSet not recognized in WebForms?

Tags: fluentvalidation

Given this validator:

```
public ThingValidator()
{
    RuleSet("Subgroup", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Apple).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Peach).NotEmpty();
    });
}
```

According to the documentation, the 'ruleSet' option should use my named ruleset. However, the  suleSet symbol cannot be resolved.

```
var validator = new ThingValidator();
var thing = new Constituent();
var results = validator.Validate(thing, ruleSet: "Subgroup");
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was stuck on this as well, but when I looked into the code, I found that while `IValidator<T>` has a `Validate` method, there are also `Validate` extensions methods in `DefaultValidatorExtensions`. The call with the `ruleSet` parameter in @mmcglynn's answer is actually to this extension method from `DefaultValidatorExtensions`:

```
public static ValidationResult Validate<T>(
    this IValidator<T> validator, T instance, 
    IValidatorSelector selector = null, 
    string ruleSet = null)
```

This is why Resharper thinks that the `ruleSet` variable is unused - because it is not actually passed in. The string "children" passed in is for the 3rd parameter called `ruleset`, whereas the second parameter (which can take the `RulesetValidatorSelector` object) defaults to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

This is extension method, declare namespace `using FluentValidation` and you can use it.

Comment: Tnx, this sloved the problem form me

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need it:

```
var results = validator.Validate(constituent, new RulesetValidatorSelector("Subgroup"));
```

or, closer to the example in the FluentValidation documentation

```
RulesetValidatorSelector ruleSet = new RulesetValidatorSelector();
var results = validator.Validate(constituent, ruleSet: "Children");
```

This will work, but ReSharper thinks that the ruleSet local variable is unused.

Comment: Instantiating a RulesetValidatorSelector does nothing to extend your validator to contain a method which has a parameter "ruleSet".  The issue is that the extension method isn't being applied.  Refer to the following..
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs#L835